# jQuery/javaScript : images don't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

I have the following code:

```
all_images = new Array(Array);
$.get('../dotclear-files/themes/biblio/js/dynamic_ajax_php.php', function(data) {
    var w = 0;
    $(data).find('image').each(function() {
        if (!all_images[w]) all_images[w] = new Array();
        all_images[w]['url'] = $(this).find('url').text() + '#comments';
        all_images[w]['src'] = $(this).find('src').text();
        all_images[w]['title'] = $(this).find('title').text();
        all_images[w]['width'] = $(this).find('width').text();
        all_images[w]['height'] = $(this).find('height').text();
        w = w + 1;
    });
    $("#carousel-comments").append('<ul></ul>');
    for (x=0; x<3; x++) {
        $('#carousel-comments ul')
            .append('<li>')
            .append('<a href="' + all_images[x]['url'] + '#comments" title="' + all_images[x]['title'] + '">')
            .append('<img alt="' + all_images[x]['title'] + '" class="jcarousel-img jcarousel-img-' + x + '" width="' + all_images[x]['width'] + 'px" height="' + all_images[x]['width'] +'px" />')
            .append('</a>')
            .append('</li>');
        var img = new Image();
        $(img)
            .load(function() {
                $('.jcarousel-img-' + x)
                    .attr({'src': all_images[x]['src'], 'alt': all_images[x]['title']})
                    .fadeIn();
                })
            .attr('src', all_images[x]['src']);
    }
    $('#carousel-comments').jcarousel('reload');
}, 'xml');
```

The first part of this code loads images from a PHP script, that returns an XML file. This part works fine.

The issue comes with the 2nd part: `$(img).load(...)` It never displays my images.

This can be seen [on my test page](http://www.mediatheque-erre.fr/test/): it's the 3rd carousel, under the title named "C'est vous qui le dites!" We can see that the titles of the images are displayed... but the images themselves aren't loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanx for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you must append the `<img>` to the carousel.

```
$(img).appendTo($("#carousel-comments"));
```

Or something like this.

**Edit** after the comments exchange:

The element `<IMG>` in your `LI` are not the same that your `var img = new Image`. Then try something like this:

```
for (x=0; x<3; x++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.load(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn();

        // Also, set your carousel here        
    });

    img.attr('alt', all_images[x]['title'])
        .attr('width', all_images[x]['width'])
        .attr('height', all_images[x]['height'])
        .addClass('jcarousel-img jcarousel-img-' + x)
        .attr('src', all_images[x]['src']);

    $('#carousel-comments ul')
        .append('li')
        .append('<a href="' + all_images[x]['url'] + '#comments" title="' + all_images[x]['title'] + '">')
        .append(img);
}
```

Comment: Mmmm... I don't think so, since the image itself is already appended to it (cf. $('#carousel-comments ul').append etc.) So all I should have to do is to set the "alt" and "src" attributes..

Comment: Yep, I just see this... But why you don't put the "src" directly in your image ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean : what I want is to wait that the image is fully loaded before to set the "src" attribute, so that the image is only displayed when it's fully loaded... Do you think there's another way to achieve this ?

Comment: Ok, what's append if you just create image without caroussel ? Is it working ?

Comment: No. It's exactly the same. The carousel only changes the position of the items (it puts them inline), and that's all...

Comment: (Re). After watching on your testsite, the img in the 'li' don't have 'src' because they are different the (var img)... You need to point the same element...

Comment: They are different... but it should have no matter : the image is loaded in the "img", but then the "src" is added to "$('.jcarousel-img-' + x)". Furthermore, the "for" loop is temporary : it will be replaced by some code proper to the carousel. So sorry, but I can't use the code you gave. Thanx anyway for trying to help ;)